QGIS is not providing me with any options in Labels, Symbology, or Masks

I am encountering an issue with QGIS where the options for Labels, Symbology, and Masks are not appearing or accessible. This problem is preventing me from properly labeling and styling my map layers, as well as applying other techniques.
How can I resolve this issue?

The "pop_vector_origin_only" layer seems to be an attribute layer without geometries. It is normal that you cannot define styles for such layers. Do you have the same issue with other layers, like "USA_Counties"?

Whenever I add a vector using the 'Delimited Text' option, I am unable to use labels, symbology, or masks.

For example, I use the 'Delimited Text' option. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uQkz-_fY-TIZU11tvVcujstUoyem1c195XoqxNX_FRk/edit?usp=sharing

Do you have geometries in your CSV? Could you show one row as an example?

The data file does not contain geometry; it consists only of column vectors, such as county names, state names, state fips, etc.

Labels and symbology are connected to geometries. Perhaps you want to join the county names etc. to the vector layer that contains the corresponding geometries? See https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html.

No, it is not a fact about the joining county names or something. It is about the QGIS, which is not providing me with any options in Labels, Symbology, or Masks. When I double-click on the CSV files, it generally allows us to work through  Labels, Symbology, etc. But I can't do that.

You might look at some of the information here including what to do if the import fails: https://mapscaping.com/converting-csv-files-into-shapefiles-with-qgis/

It is not possible to configure labels or rendering styles for the non-spatial tables https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#foreword-spatial-and-non-spatial-tables. Because the featured are without geometries, there is nothing to show on the map so this limitation in not surprising.
With these CSV files it is possible to test the QGIS user interface
wkt.csv
=======
WKT,PLACE_NAME
"POINT (0 0)","Null Island"

attribute.csv
=============
PLACE_NAME
"Null Island"

When layers are added to QGIS the wkt layer appears as a point layer, and the attribute layer appears as a non-spatial layer.

For the non-spatial layer it is not possible to define styles.

For the imported point layer it is possible to define styles, and QGIS creates the default styles automatically.

You wrote:

The data file does not contain geometry; it consists only of column
vectors, such as county names, state names, state fips, etc.

You have a non-spatial layer so you cannot apply styles or labels into it.
